# N access point connected to G router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-router

Any issues connecting an N access point via an ethernet cable to a G router?

I currently have a wrt54gl router in one room (where it's connected by cables to various devices). I'm usually in another room and connect via wifi with other devices.  Internet speeds over wifi are fine, but speeds are too slow when transferring files from wifi devices to other computers (windows file sharing).

I'm thinking of running a cable through a wall from the wrt54gl room to the other room and connecting a small N router, in access point mode. I'd then connect to the N access point and, through it, to the main router and other devices in the network.

All wifi devices can run N.

Are there any issues in doing this?

Anything I should know about configuring this? From other questions, it's not clear if I should use the same SSID for both routers. For that matter, should I turn off wifi on the wrt54gl?

I see a number of similar questions, but none exactly on point. If I've missed something, please link.

Comment: Setup works nicely. I set up the new router with another SSID. New router is working as an N access point, old is still on G.

Answer (score 0):

I see no issues with this setup, in fact according to smallnetbuilder this is actually the preferable way to handle the issue of needing N wireless.

http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/30224-add-dont-replace-when-upgrading-to-80211n

That page also lists some of the things you will want to consider when setting things up such as wireless channels ect.